# Actionscript 3 TextField bug with htmlText?

Tags: actionscript-3

I embed text in textfield, but sometimes it does not render using htmltext.  if I use text it renders fine.

Comment: `htmlText` has some issues - give some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset defaultTextFormat every time I assign htmlText, nad it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct embedded font's turned on for that textfield